# How to listen for layer loading failure

Tags: openlayers-6

I saw the official error event, but I don't know how to use it; When I am in addlayer, the layer loading fails and the page is blank. I want to listen for error events. How do you use it?
The URL of source is incorrect and inaccessible.

```js
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                url: url,
                strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
            }),
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: rgbList[0]
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'black',
                    width: 1
                })
            })
        })
map.addLayer(vector);
```

My page is blank and addlayer reports an error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ol_uid').

Answer (score 0):

If it is a data loading problem you can listen for these errors on the source of the layer. Depending on the source type the event is called `featuresloaderror`, `tileloaderror`, or `imageloaderror`.

Without some actual code it's hard to help you further.